# Ubuntu 14.04 how to install cuda 6.5 without installing nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I am working on workstation with CPU core I7 4790 and two GPUs GTX 760 4 GB ram/1152 core
the system's memory is 16 GB RAM 
I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 
after many tries and reinstalling Ubuntu many times finally i have correctly installed nvidia driver 340.46  using 3 shell commands ppa xorg-edgers

now i want to install Cuda 6.5 toolkit
but in the manual they say that the cuda toolkit installer will also install nvidia Graphics driver

how to prevent the installer from reinstall the graphics driver 
how to install cuda 6.5 toolkit without reinstalling my graphics driver 
because i faced many problems until i installed 340.46 correctly

and after successfully installing cuda toolkit 6.5 how to upgrade my graphics driver without disturbing cuda toolkit and reinstall everything from the beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install aptitude

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and then run

```
aptitude
```

Click on <kbd>Search</kbd> type `nvidia`, use the arrow keys to go to `nvidia-340.46` and click on <kbd>Package</kbd> and then <kbd>Hold</kbd>.

(and then still take a full system backup before installing CUDA; I use CloneZilla as a system backup: just take the `/` partition and leave the `/home` partition out!  Works like a charm!)

Also, now you *have* `aptitude`, so even if things go wrong, you can still log into the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and use `aptitude` to delete whatever CUDA installed....

Comment: i have installed nvidia 340.58 graphics driver and then i have installed cuda toolkit 6.5 from cuda repo .deb package   and everything worked well i performed post installation steps and i run nvcc -v command it worked will but the samples cannot be run it says my gcc is 4.9.2 and it is not supported by cuda  it says 4.8.2 supported what can i do ?

Comment: I have an NVidia card and I use Xorg.edgers too and I know what CUDA is... I have yet to write my first C-program on Linux...  Still at the bash stage, next is go, then back to C.  Ask me again in a year or so!  ;-)

Comment: Hold on! I've got gcc 4.8.2...  What's your `uname -r`?

Comment: uname -r  3.13.0-40-generic  i have gcc 4.9.2

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: any way thanks faby for your answers and comments  i really appreciate that

Comment: I've got 3.13.0-34. We should both go to bed!  Good night!!!  ;-)

Comment: So, did you manage to decouple the graphics driver from CUDA in any particular way? All I see on this answer is some tinkering advice. Reason I ask is I'd like to use the Nvidia card's CUDA, while a Radeon (i.e. non-Nvidia) card is used for display.

Comment: @matt: Simple, just [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this question if it helps provide context.  **;-)**  I know nothing about Radeon, so I can't help you with that, but someone else might.